# How to Spring framework and MySQL with Java swing application?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, swing, jdbc

I have a Java swing app where I would like to use Spring framework and connect with MySQL database with JDBC. It is a project from a friend that I would like to help, so, nothing related to job. My knowledge of Spring framework and JDBC is little more than basic. **THE DATABASE CONNECTION IS NOT WORKING AND I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE A SOLUTION FOR THAT.** The whole project structure is as following,

[image]

As you see that the project has 3 main packages ( *com.dev.frontend.config, com.dev.frontend.panels and com.dev.frontend.services*; inside the panels there are 2 sub-packages: *edit* and *list* )

Here is how I'm progressing.

1. I get the dependencies using the pom.xml file and update the Maven project. These are the dependencies that I have currently showing in the picture. [image]
2. I'm using Apache tomcat v8.0 as server and inside the context.xml file, I updated the database information as following,

**

```
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/spring" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" username="student"
            password="student" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mySalesApp1" />
</Context>
```

**
This provides server the user name, password and the database name.

3. I add a new WebContent folder in the project and put web.xml and offers-servlet.xml file there as following,
   [image]

The web.xml file goes as following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>MySpringMVC</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>offers</display-name>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <description>Spring Database</description>
  <resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/spring</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:com/dev/frontend/config/dao-context.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>

</web-app>
```

the program knows the database connect from `<resource-ref>` tag. The offers-servlet.xml file is referenced from the web.xml file but I don't make any use of that. In the end of this file, there is `<context-param>` tag that tells to scan inside the *config* package to look for *dao-context.xml* file.

4. The dao-context.xml goes as following,

   [image]

It knows the database connection using the `<jee:jndi-lookup>` tag and look for the services package.

5. Inside the services package, there is *Services.java* source file and I'm trying to do some query as following,

   ```
     @Component("Services")
     public class Services {


   private static NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc;

   @Autowired
   public void setDataSource(DataSource jdbc) {

       this.jdbc = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbc);
   }

   public static List<Customer> getMyCustomer() {

       return jdbc.query("select * from Customer", new RowMapper<Customer>(){

           public Customer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                   throws SQLException {

               Customer customer = new Customer();

               customer.setCustomerID(rs.getString("CustomerID"));
               customer.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
               customer.setAddress(rs.getNString("Address"));
               customer.setPhone1(rs.getNString("Phone 1"));
               customer.setPhone2(rs.getNString("Phone 2"));

               customer.setCreditLimit(rs.getDouble("Credit Limit"));
               customer.setCurrentCredit(rs.getDouble("Current Credit"));

               return customer;
           }
       });
   }

   }
   ```

The SQL query inside the *getMyCustomer()* is not working and returning the following errors,

[image]

How to solve this problem and connect properly with the database ? Thanks.

Comment: Just a remark: your version of Spring is old _and_ has known security issues. Update to a current 3.2 or 4.x

Comment: Updated to <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

While upgrading to Spring 4, you could use:

File: database-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured />
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class = "true"/>

    <bean id="emf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="your.jpa.generated"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://yourserver:3306/yourdatabase" />
        <property name="username" value="youruser" />
        <property name="password" value="yourpassword" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

Then in your class add:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

And use the EntityManager for your queries.

Comment: Do I need to use these code in the dao-context,xml file ? I put the database informations inside the conext.xml file in Tomcat server and thought I would be able to use that information in the program.

Comment: This is a spring configuration xml file. You need to a reference to it in the web.xml